JAX-RS uri template not capturing expected string
I have a simple api
@GET
@Path("res/{res-path :.*}")
public Response getRes(@PathParam("res-path") String resource) {

   System.out.println(resource);
}

I was under impression that this should capture anything after res/ into resource but it is not the case !
URL : res/res2 -----> Prints res2 (accepted)
URL : res/res2/res3 -----> Prints res2/res3 (accepted)
BUT
URL : res/res -----> Prints EMPTY STRING (instead of res/)
URL : res/res/res2 -----> Prints res2 (instead of res/res2)
Any suggestions or thoughts?

What is your goal ?

To have an api to show folders and files and ability to drill into folders.
Like:
folder1/foder2/file1

re: your original title/tags, URI templates don't use regex.
